# AngularJs, Updating Data From One Central Service When Using $http

Tags: angularjs, rest

I'm trying to wrap my head around sharing data between controllers in Angular. This is my first project with Angular.

So far it looks like a "service" is one way I can share data between two or more controllers. The data needs to be "live". The data is retrieved from the server using Angular's $http service.

The problem I'm having is that I don't understand how I can add to the data once it's bee fetched from the server. I have a function which is supposed to push new data onto one central array (in the service) and this must automatically update everywhere else in the app. I've condensed my code so you can see what I'm trying to do. I may be going in the wrong direction, so feel free to advice how I should be doing this. Many thanks.

```
// Setup a factory for processing posts and their data
app.factory( "AllEvents", [ "$http", function AllEventsFactory ( $http ) {
    // Hold all posts from the database
    var allEvents = [];

    // Retrieve posts and return a promise object
    function getEvents () {
        // Retrieve events from the database
        return $http( {
            method: "GET",
            url: "foo",
        } );
    }

    // Allow a new post to be pushed onto the allEvents array
    function pushNewEvent ( newEvent ) {
        allEvents.push( newEvent ); // This needs to update "globally"
    }

    return {
        getEvents: getEvents, // Get the events for the first time. TODO, only send $http request once.
        pushNewEvent: pushNewEvent // Allow new events to be pushed on this object
    }
} ] );

app.controller( "ExistingEventsController", [ "$scope", "AllEvents", function ( $scope, AllEvents ) {
    // Get all current events from the AllEvents service using the promise object
    AllEvents.getEvents().then(
        function successCallback ( data ) {
            $scope.events = data.data; // NOTE: I need this to be updated when the AllEvents.allEvents property is updated from other controllers
        },
        function errorCallback ( data ) {
            // Handle the error
            console.log( "There was an error" );
        }
    );
} ] );

app.controller( "NewEventController", [ "$scope", "$http", "$timeout", "AllEvents", function( $scope, $http, $timeout, AllEvents ) {
    $scope.addNewEvent = function ( newEventData ) {
        // Sample data
        var newEventData = {
            post_title : "This is my example title"
        };

        AllEvents.pushNewEvent( newEventData ); // NOTE: How should this work..?
    }
} ] );
```

Comment: Do you need to post the new events back to the server?

Comment: @yarons Yes, I do. I think I may have this sorted though, I used a promise, as seen in the code above, but then I set the results on the Service using a setter. If this works out OK I'll update the code here to show what I've done.